# Integration tests in VSTS

Tags: c#, sql-server, azure-devops, integration-testing

We have many external libraries written in C#. Those libraries integrate with other ERP program. Each library is written for diffrent company. We are building those libraries using VSTS. We added to them unit tests. They works fine localy in VS and in VSTS. Each company has his own data base wchich differs a little. Now we are adding integration tests with clients data bases. Locally in VS everything is fine. Integration tests are passing when our code is ok.

We would like to move integration tests to VSTS. The best solutions would be if we could store client data bases somewhere for VSTS use only, and has acces them during test in VSTS. But we don't know how to do this. Any help how to do this would be very welcome.

**Update:**
Data base type: MS SQL.
Integration tests are done using .dll files provided by ERP producer. To make this kind of test we have to be able to acces data base. Locally this is no problem. I don't know how VSTS build definition could have acces to data base. Where I can store data base for that kind of acces.

Comment: Can you show more detail informations here? Such as what's the databases does your clients used? How did you integrated tests with data bases? And how would you like VSTS store client data bases? etc. And the document may related, you can refer Perform SQL server actions in VSTS or TFS (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/pipelines/apps/cd/sql-server-actions?view=vsts).

Answer (score 0):

To access to SQL Server database, you can execute `sqlpackage` command in a **PowerShell task**.

More details, you can refer the document [Perform SQL server actions in VSTS or TFS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/pipelines/apps/cd/sql-server-actions?view=vsts).

[image]

Comment: Thanks for answer, we decided to move our builds to Jenkins. There we are able to achive everything we need more easly.